# Python: Какой инструмент для работы с БД выбрать

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Только начинаю изучать python, возникли проблемы с базами данных.
Сначала выбрала pymysql, все шло хорошо.
Сейчас решила переписать все запросы к БД через подготовленные операторы, чтобы везде где нужно кавычки проставились / экранировались (ну и + безопасность).

Мои запросы сейчас:

```
sql = "UPDATE myTable SET {q} = {answ} WHERE userid = {id};".format(id=userId, q=q, answ=answ)
cur.execute(sql)
```

Хочу сделать так:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE myTable SET %s = %s WHERE userid = %s", (q, answ, userId))
```

но оказалось, что pymysql не поддерживает prepared statements (вычитала тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671286/does-pymysql-support-prepared-statements), и код вызывает ошибку:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "'q1' = 0 WHERE userid = 0" at line 1

Так же, хочу заметить, что в качестве answ может передаваться и число и строка. userId - число длиной до 20 символов, поэтому я сделала его varchar

В поисках информации нашла, что можно вместо pymysql использовать mysql.connector, но он вроде устарел (?)
Есть еще MySQLdb, там должен работать такой код.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что лучше выбрать.
Пишу бота для телеграм, кроме работы с БД толком ничего не понадобиться.

Может вообще есть смысл сменить MySql на что-то другое? (правда я уже столько времени на установку настройку потратила, что не очень хочется:) )

**UPD:**
Обновила пост с учетом комментариев

Comment: «pymysql не поддерживает prepared statements» — неправда, в показанном вами виде поддерживает. // «код вызывает ошибку» — какую ошибку?

Comment: Для указания названия таблицы используется специальный синтаксис в sql, поэтому такая подстановка, которую вы пытаетесь сделать, работать не будет ни в каком инструменте. Вообще, зачем вам вдруг понадобилось подставлять название таблицы? Обычно названия таблиц всегда фиксированные и их можно написать прямо в sql-коде без всяких подстановок, почему у вас не так?

Comment: Я даже не думала, что имя базы нельзя так передавать. Код буду использовать для нескольких разных таблиц, хотела как можно меньше править, поэтому решила делать подстановкой.
Попробовала с указанием имени таблицы, все равно не работает. Обновила пост, обновила свои запросы и подписала текст ошибки

Comment: Я сперва не обратил внимания, но вообще названия колонок в таблице тоже нельзя так передавать, можно только значения (то есть только answ и userId в данном случае)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо! Действительно, с явным указанием имени столбца заработало. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю заранее, в какой столбец записывать. Я понимаю, что я могу раскопировать этот запрос (и другие тоже тогда) кучу раз для разных столбцов, но будет очень громоздко. Но в таком случае, мне проще вернуться к варианту без подготовленных операторов. Неужели нельзя как-то имя столбца через переменную передать?((

Comment: @andreymal, нашла!) Правильный вариант: `cur.execute(f"UPDATE {table} SET {q} = %s WHERE userid = %s", (answ, userId))`
P.S. Не подскажите, что теперь делать с моим постом? Он получился совсем не про то. Нужно изменить тему и все переписать?